# Loading images in array Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Which is the best way to store images in an array? I'm using `ImageIO` and I now wish to store them in an array.

Comment: Do you want the array to hold, byte for byte, the data in the image file?

Comment: I want to store all the pixels of the image in an array or list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PixelGrabber](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) is what you want.

```
Image img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("img.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int w = img.getWidth(null);
int h = img.getHeight(null);
int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
try {
    pg.grabPixels();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("interrupted waiting for pixels!");
    return;
}
if ((pg.getStatus() & ImageObserver.ABORT) != 0) {
    System.err.println("image fetch aborted or errored");
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    System.out.println(pixels[i]);
```

Comment: Xm this is the easiest way? I mean how i could store my image in a 3d array for every colour? I want to compute the histogram for every color finally.

Comment: Can ask sth else? What is goin to be the format of the pixels values? I got numbers like -14277082 this stands for the triplette fo RGB??

Answer (score 3):

If you read the whole images in memory, you can store them in `List<byte[]>` or `List<BufferedImage>`.

Otherwise you can simply store their paths as `List<String>`.

If you really need an array, you can instead use `BufferedImage[]`, or use `list.toArray(..)`

Comment: I wan to store the whole images so as to processing them.  I use this command to BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(); to read them. Then next step is to just store image in an List?